# Trying to deploy Strapi CMS with TypeScript to Railway and get: "Cannot find module 'typescript'"

Tags: typescript, deployment, strapi, railway

### Details

Trying to deploy strapi CMS written in TypeScript to Railway. I know there's a JavaScript Template, annoyingly there's not a TypeScript Template and there's nothing on the docs about deployment to Railway with TypeScript.

#### Error logs from Railway

Here's the error logs from railway. I think it might be trying to compile the JavaScript files but I've set the compiler to ignore node modules.

```
#13 6.049 Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
#13 6.049 Require stack:
#13 6.049 - /app/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/typescript/type-script-worker-config.js
#13 6.049 - /app/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/plugin-config.js
#13 6.049 - /app/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/plugin.js
#13 6.049 - /app/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/index.js
#13 6.049 - /app/node_modules/@strapi/admin/webpack.config.js
#13 6.049 - /app/node_modules/@strapi/admin/utils/get-custom-webpack-config.js
#13 6.049 - /app/node_modules/@strapi/admin/utils/index.js
#13 6.049 - /app/node_modules/@strapi/admin/index.js
#13 6.049 - /app/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/commands/builders/admin.js
#13 6.049 - /app/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/commands/builders/index.js
#13 6.049 - /app/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/commands/build.js
#13 6.049 - /app/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js
#13 6.049     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
#13 6.049     at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:19)
 
#13 6.049     at createTypeScriptWorkerConfig (/app/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/typescript/type-script-worker-config.js:16:70)
#13 6.049     at createPluginConfig (/app/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/plugin-config.js:11:82)
#13 6.049     at ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin.apply (/app/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/plugin.js:57:63)
#13 6.049     at createCompiler (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:73:12)
#13 6.049     at create (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:134:16)
#13 6.049     at webpack (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:158:32)
#13 6.049     at f (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js:64:16)
#13 6.049     at Object.build (/app/node_modules/@strapi/admin/index.js:60:20) {
#13 6.049   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
#13 6.049   requireStack: [
#13 6.049     '/app/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/typescript/type-script-worker-config.js',
#13 6.049     '/app/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/plugin-config.js',
#13 6.049     '/app/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/plugin.js',
#13 6.049     '/app/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/index.js',
#13 6.049     '/app/node_modules/@strapi/admin/webpack.config.js',
#13 6.049     '/app/node_modules/@strapi/admin/utils/get-custom-webpack-config.js',
#13 6.049     '/app/node_modules/@strapi/admin/utils/index.js',
#13 6.049     '/app/node_modules/@strapi/admin/index.js',
#13 6.049     '/app/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/commands/builders/admin.js',
#13 6.049     '/app/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/commands/builders/index.js',
#13 6.049     '/app/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/commands/build.js',
#13 6.049     '/app/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js'
#13 6.049   ]
#13 6.049 }
```

#### tsconfig.json

Configuration for TypeScript compiler.

```json
{
  "extends": "@strapi/typescript-utils/tsconfigs/server",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "."
  },
  "include": [
    "./",
    "./**/*.ts",
    "./**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.json"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/",
    "build/",
    "dist/",
    ".cache/",
    ".tmp/",
    "src/admin/",
    "**/*.test.*",
    "src/plugins/**"
  ]
}
```

#### Package.json

Here's the package.json which is from the typescript quickstart template.

```json
{
  "name": "aston-and-fincher-intranet-cms",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/plugin-graphql": "^4.9.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.9.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.9.0",
    "@strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary": "^4.9.0",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.9.0",
    "better-sqlite3": "8.0.1"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "George Fincher"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "3a5b99f5-14e8-4962-80ef-dcf9bb469d41"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.19.1 <=18.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

### What I've Tried

I've followed the instructions on deploying with TypeScript, my tsconfig.json should be fine. I've added the additional environment variables but it seems like that has nothing to do with the error logs.

Any help would be much appreciated as I would rather not go with the JavaScript version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, it wasn't included in the docs, but they literally hadn't installed typescript as a dependency. Going to file an issue with Strapi now. Should've realized this sooner. Oh well ‍♂️.

If anyone else encounters this just do an `npm install typescript`. That fixed everything for me.